# Regex for twitter usernames but for some matching a specified format - Python

Tags: python, regex

I am new to Regular Expressions. I am currently trying to replace all of the usernames within tweets with @MENTION except for the ones that I previously already changed into @CEO, @COMPANY, and @MEDIA.

The final solution should work like this:
Initial tweet: "@John was told by the @COMPANY that he wouldn't receive his bonus, @MEDIA reported."
Final tweet: "@MENTION was told by the @COMPANY that he wouldn't receive his bonus, @MEDIA reported."

I tried the different versions  but couldn't resolve them.If you could help it would be very much appreciated.

This was an attempt, I got it doing the opposite of what I would like but I couldn't resolve it.

```
pattern = re.compile("@(MEDIA)|(CEO)|(EMPLOYEE)")
test = ["hello @CEO said the @user in the @MEDIA", "there is a new @EMPLOYEE said the @user"]
for t in test:
    test = [re.sub(pattern,"USER",t) for t in test]
test

>>>['hello @USER said the @user in the USER', 'there is a new @USER said the @user']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<!\S)@(?!COMPANY|CEO|MEDIA)\b[^@\s]+
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<!\S)@` Assert a whitespace boundary to the left, then match @
- `(?!COMPANY|CEO|MEDIA)\b` Negative lookahead to assert not any of the alternatives directly to the right
- `[^@\s]+` match 1+ times any char except @ or a whitspace char.

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yhGuXk/1) or a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/10Ka9o)

In the replacement you could use `"@MENTION"`

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"(?<!\S)@(?!COMPANY|CEO|MEDIA)\b[^@\s]+")
test = ["hello @CEO said the @user in the @MEDIA", "there is a new @EMPLOYEE said the @user"]
for t in test:
    test = re.sub(pattern, "@MENTION", t)
    print(test)
```

Output

```
hello @CEO said the @MENTION in the @MEDIA
there is a new @MENTION said the @MENTION
```